# How to make a TextView that starts with the beginning of the first pixel of text in it?

Tags: android, textview

Here is my problem - I want `TextView` to fit `|` exactly from the left at least but even though I've set `gravity` to `left`, there are still some "empty pixels" to the left of `|` sign in the `TextView` and I want to prevent it from happening. How should I approach this problem?

Here are properties of a TextView I want to achieve the effect on:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="|"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textColor="#ff16de2e"
        android:id="@+id/cursor"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButton"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/startButton" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this for your TextView.

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

and to make sure the View does not extend beyond it's content use

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

If this still doesn't look like what you want, you can manually play with TextView's padding and do something like this:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\u007C"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:padding="-1.5dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
```

Comment: On which Android version are you testing? 
Can you post your layout in your question? It could provide more info to the problem!

Comment: 4.4.4, added my TextView properties in original post

Comment: ok, changing `android:padding` value finally worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help :). 
The idea is that the font has some internal padding. If you want to be extra safe you could find(or make) an font which has no internal padding and you should have the desired effect without playing with the View's padding.